# How to handle missing intermediate certificate in Java

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

Is there a way to handle in Java when an HTTPS connection to a server fails due to missing intermediate certificate issue on the server side. Essentially, I am encountering the issue discussed here 
[OpenSSL: unable to verify the first certificate for Experian URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587851/openssl-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-for-experian-url)

Is my only good option to import the certificate into my trusted keystore or is there something else I can do on the fly even if say just for this particular URL ? In the accepted solution for the provided link how does one do "..or passing the missing intermediate certificate to OpenSSL as a client-side parameter."