# Giitea Webhook x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: jenkins, openshift, gitea

On openshift cluster i deployed gitea v1.9.0 and i added a webhook for triggering the pipeline, now i'm getting the following error:

> Delivery: Post
>   https://ip@:8443/apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/jenkins/buildconfigs/pipeline6/webhooks/somesecret/generic:
>   x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

How can i disable ssl verification in Gitea ? And is there another way to trigger the build in openshift's pipeline ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no possibility to disable the ssl verification in Gitea AFAIK.

I had the same error by the integration with Jenkins. The problem was that Gitea does not support the "certificate discovery" feature (as for example a browser like Firefox does, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587851/openssl-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-for-experian-url/7644229#7644229)) and Jenkins was misconfigured and was sending only the end entity certificate.

After making Jenkins to send the entire certificate chain, the problem disappeared.