# Jenkins and Kubernetes plugin Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: java, kubernetes, ssl, jenkins, cryptography

I am running Jenkins inside k8s cluster(1.25.5) with CRI-O and ingress-nginx deployed by kubespray and it is installed by this helm chart:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts

I installed the latest Kubernetes plugin but I can't connect to Kubernetes cluster.
I am getting this error:
[image]

I tried to make diagnose so I enabled ssl handshake debug in Jenkins and getting these values:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|77|Handling POST /manage/descriptorByName/org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud/testConnection from 78.45.197.14 : Jetty (winstone)-119|2023-01-08 14:16:53.525 CET|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:365|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe2048
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|77|Handling POST /manage/descriptorByName/org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud/testConnection from 78.45.197.14 : Jetty (winstone)-119|2023-01-08 14:16:53.525 CET|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:365|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe3072
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|77|Handling POST /manage/descriptorByName/org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud/testConnection from 78.45.197.14 : Jetty (winstone)-119|2023-01-08 14:16:53.525 CET|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:365|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe4096
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|77|Handling POST /manage/descriptorByName/org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud/testConnection from 78.45.197.14 : Jetty (winstone)-119|2023-01-08 14:16:53.525 CET|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:365|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe6144
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|77|Handling POST /manage/descriptorByName/org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud/testConnection from 78.45.197.14 : Jetty (winstone)-119|2023-01-08 14:16:53.525 CET|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:365|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe8192
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|77|Handling POST /manage/descriptorByName/org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud/testConnection from 78.45.197.14 : Jetty (winstone)-119|2023-01-08 14:16:53.526 CET|SessionTicketExtension.java:408|Stateless resumption supported
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|77|Handling POST /manage/descriptorByName/org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud/testConnection from 78.45.197.14 : Jetty (winstone)-119|2023-01-08 14:16:53.527 CET|ClientHello.java:641|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "08D49711B6FB43B5C3BB9E5EE3A61BDE866BA66CDE9152DBC67B25A0E67C4BD0",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA9), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA8), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x448]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "application_layer_protocol_negotiation (16)": {
      [h2, http/1.1]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "session_ticket (35)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, ed25519, ed448, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.2]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, ed25519, ed448, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|77|Handling POST /manage/descriptorByName/org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud/testConnection from 78.45.197.14 : Jetty (winstone)-119|2023-01-08 14:16:53.528 CET|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "protocol_version"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|77|Handling POST /manage/descriptorByName/org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud/testConnection from 78.45.197.14 : Jetty (winstone)-119|2023-01-08 14:16:53.531 CET|TransportContext.java:363|Fatal (PROTOCOL_VERSION): Received fatal alert: protocol_version (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1505)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:320)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:284)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:169)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:258)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:127)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:257)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:93)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientImpl.send(OkHttpClientImpl.java:138)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.retryWithExponentialBackoff(OperationSupport.java:574)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:553)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:518)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:502)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.listRequestHelper(BaseOperation.java:133)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:415)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:404)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:83)
        at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud$DescriptorImpl.doTestConnection(KubernetesCloud.java:744)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:732)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:397)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:409)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:78)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:207)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:140)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:558)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:289)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:836)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$9.dispatch(MetaClass.java:475)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:698)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:248)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:764)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1665)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
        at hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm$2.doFilter(HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm.java:1022)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
        at hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm$2.doFilter(HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm.java:1022)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
        at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:81)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
        at hudson.plugins.locale.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:42)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
        at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:129)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:248)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
        at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
        at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:60)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
        at jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
        at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:94)
        at jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:54)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:101)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:97)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:63)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:111)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:172)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
        at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:549)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1570)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1543)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$0(HttpChannel.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:762)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:416)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:385)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:272)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.lambda$new$0(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:934)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1078)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)}

)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|77|Handling POST /manage/descriptorByName/org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud/testConnection from 78.45.197.14 : Jetty (winstone)-119|2023-01-08 14:16:53.532 CET|SSLSocketImpl.java:1754|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|77|Handling POST /manage/descriptorByName/org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud/testConnection from 78.45.197.14 : Jetty (winstone)-119|2023-01-08 14:16:53.532 CET|SSLSocketImpl.java:1780|close the SSL connection (passive)
```

Also when I tried this command

```
openssl s_client -connect kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443
```

I am getting this:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = kube-apiserver
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = kube-apiserver
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = kube-apiserver
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = kube-apiserver
   i:CN = kubernetes
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Dec 30 13:24:38 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Jan  2 02:10:40 2024 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = kube-apiserver
issuer=CN = kubernetes
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
CN = kubernetes
CN = front-proxy-ca
Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA-PSS+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:Ed25519:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:0x01+0x02:0x03+0x02
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA-PSS+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:Ed25519:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1679 bytes and written 434 bytes
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    Session-ID: 0468FD5467824F8B449513B6A09E2D975CD1690AE5DFBD0B3BB713AD4D86D02C
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: 3BC22E3A910C771317E8F624DAB40723E70802964B2230AE31E9E37F211E1EDF
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 604800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 59 da 44 7f 6c f7 bf 1f-95 3e 4c 90 34 b0 5e 4b   Y.D.l....>L.4.^K
    0010 - 5f b4 78 ca fd 3a 84 62-4a a3 d8 f7 56 eb 9e 6f   _.x..:.bJ...V..o
    0020 - f2 15 38 e1 38 de 57 07-c0 c4 ef 4b b9 0f ac 7c   ..8.8.W....K...|
    0030 - 18 6a ba 7e 25 ce df b8-a5 8e 45 8d c8 30 3a 91   .j.~%.....E..0:.
    0040 - 7c fc 53 d3 09 e0 12 7b-61 be 83 29 a3 f5 49 52   |.S....{a..)..IR
    0050 - 66 5c 52 5f 10 4f f0 d5-b7 d6 91 02 39 b8 0d 32   f\R_.O......9..2
    0060 - f9 9d 47 59 50 7b cc c3-bd 4e 29 dc 6c 82 b1 4b   ..GYP{...N).l..K
    0070 - e2                                                .

    Start Time: 1673186073
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
closed
```

Does anyone know how to fix that, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding this to the JVM settings:

"-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2" and also check versions compatibility..refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587851/openssl-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-for-experian-url) & [link](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/issues/893) for more information

Comment: It didn't helped :( ```java -Duser.home=/var/jenkins_home -Dcasc.reload.token=jenkins-0 -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djenkins.model.Jenkins.slaveAgentPort=50000 -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.ExitLifecycle -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/jenkins_cache/war --httpPort=8080```

Comment: Versions compatibility ? refer this [link](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-37643)